# Laravel 5 Sql exception, but SQL runs fine?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this exception:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 624:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? ? and ? ? ?' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `recipients` where firstname != 'Test' and firstname = 'Jodie')
```

When the SQL it states, works fine in a console? The query before being prepared is:

```
select * from `recipients` where ? ? ? and ? ? ?
```

I'm clearly doing something stupid, but I'm completely stumped, as it's not at all complex...

Comment: Are you binding a condition and not just a value?

Comment: I'm binding everything; Field, condition and value. It's for custom built filtering. Is that the problem?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I recall that you should bind only values, if you want to have dynamic queries - you can't bind those parts.

Comment: Show us your PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ofir Baruch pointed out, I'm not able to bind everything as I was (field, conditional operator and value). I've since replaced the prepared statement with only binding on values and it's working.

What is odd however, is that from the original exception, the final sql that was created was perfect. Just, couldn't use it.